# How to get the offset in a file in flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am rather new to flash/actionscript and I have encountered a problem. I need to get the current offset in a text file, in bytes.

Java has a nice little function called *getFilePointer* that does exactly that, but I need it in actionscript. Any help would be dearly appreciated!

Comment: Can you give us a code sample of what you have so far?  It will make it much easier to tell you what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By offset you mean the position of the file pointer?

Use the position property of the ByteArray class to read or set the position of the file pointer: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html#position